# I want to get minimun number's index for a row excluding zeros

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

Consider the following code that generates the following `dst` matrix.

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame()
tmp['a'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
tmp['b'] = np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)
dst = pairwise_distances(tmp, tmp, metric='l2')
dst
```

which looks like the following

`array([[0.        , 5.38516481, 5.        , 4.12310563, 2.        ],`
 `[5.38516481, 0.        , 1.41421356, 3.16227766, 5.        ],`
 `[5.        , 1.41421356, 0.        , 4.        , 4.12310563],`
 `[4.12310563, 3.16227766, 4.        , 0.        , 5.        ],`
 `[2.        , 5.        , 4.12310563, 5.        , 0.        ]])`

Now, I want to somehow get `4` as an output column, because for `row=0 and col=4` lies the minimum distance of `row0` to another row apart from itself.
I'm trying to use the following code to do the job! but   `np.nonzeros()` is messing up the game.
`np.argmin(dst[0, np.nonzero(dst[0,:])])` I'm getting `3` as an output, where I should be getting `4`. I understand that `np.nonzero()` return another set of dimensions `[1,2,3,4]` of which `argmin` picks `3rd` column which is actual `4th` column of the `dst` matrix. Need help! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `argmin`, use `np.min` and compare the result to `dst[0,:]`. Finally, pass it to `np.flatnonzero` or `np.nonzero`

```
np.flatnonzero(np.min(dst[0,np.nonzero(dst[0,:])]) == dst[0,:])

Out[150]: array([4], dtype=int64)
```

Or

```
np.nonzero(np.min(dst[0,np.nonzero(dst[0,:])]) == dst[0,:])[0]

Out[151]: array([4], dtype=int64)
```

---

If you want to return an integer index, you may use `np.argmax` at the last step

```
np.argmax(np.min(dst[0,np.nonzero(dst[0,:])]) == dst[0,:])

Out[157]: 4
```